# CodePipeline - CodeBuild and CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have a CodeBuild job that builds a zip file as an artifact and pushes it to s3 ( not sure if I need the second step still.. ).  the next stage runs CodeDeploy, how do I tell that stage to use the zip file I just built to deploy it ?

it looks like the logs in CodeDeploy fail at the first step, and when I go to look at the archive on the EC2, the folder doesn't exist.

the CodeDeploy and CodeBuild jobs work great independently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodePipeline automatically creates a S3 bucket for artifacts it generates when you create your pipeline. You have to specify the files included in your CodeBuild artifact that can be deployable by CodeDeploy. CodePipeline will know the location of the CodeBuild artifact from the Build step, and use it when creating the CodeDeploy deployment.

Here's a tutorial showing how to integrate CodeBuild and CodeDeploy with CodePipeline: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KppUHzb4kHc